# Ошибка TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Моя вторая программа. Не могу понять где ошибка, при запуске вылетает ошибка "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation в Python"

Вот код:

```
while True:
    from colorama import init
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

    # use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
    init()

    print( Fore.BLACK )
    print( Back.YELLOW )

    a = input( "Укажите ваш пол.[муж, жен]:")
    b = input("Укажите свой рост (в см.):")
    c = input( "Укажите ваш вес (только цифры):")

    print( Back.CYAN )

    if a == "Женский" or a == "женский" or a == "жен." or a == "tycrbq":
        i = (b - 100) - (165 - 150) / 2
        w = c - i
        print( "Ваш идеальный вес:" + i + "кг." )
        print( "Вам нужно похудеть на " + w + "кг." )

        print( Back.GREEN )

    elif a == "Муж." or a == "муж" or a =="мужской" or a == "Мужской":
        q = (b - 100) * 1.5
        e = c - q
        print( "Ваш идеальный вес:" + q + "кг." )
        print( "Вам нужно похудеть на " + e + "кг." )
    qw = input("Начать заново? [Да, Нет]: ")
    if qw == "no" or qw == "нет" or qw == "Нет" or qw == "не" or qw == "нее" or qw =="ytn":
        break
```

Comment: В коде присутствуют и  пробелы, и табы для отступов. Замените табы пробелами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    from colorama import init

    init()

    a = input("Укажите ваш пол.[муж, жен]:")
    b = int(input("Укажите свой рост (в см.):"))
    c = int(input("Укажите ваш вес (только цифры):"))

    if a == "Женский" or a == "женский" or a == "жен." or a == "tycrbq":
        i = (b - 100) - (165 - 150) / 2
        w = c - i
        print(f"Ваш идеальный вес: {i}.")
        print(f"Вам нужно похудеть на {w} кг.")

    elif a == "Муж." or a == "муж" or a == "мужской" or a == "Мужской":
        q = (b - 100) * 1.5
        e = int(c) - int(q)
        print(f"Ваш идеальный вес: {q} кг.")
        print(f"Вам нужно похудеть на {e} кг.")
    qw = input("Начать заново? [Да, Нет]: ")
    if qw == "no" or qw == "нет" or qw == "Нет" or qw == "не" or qw == "нее" or qw == "ytn":
        break
```